# PopUp composable covers the keyboard when it's open

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to make a searchable TextField, whenever the user enters the data Popup displays which consists of filtered data.

the problem is that Popup, when it's open covers the keyboard:

[image]

How can this be avoided?

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at any of your code, I suspect what you're missing is to add the `.imePadding()` modifier into your Composable in order to account for the screen real state that the IME (keyboard) is taking up.

```
modifier = Modifier.imePadding()
```

Nevertheless, I would recommend you not only consider moving the pop higher in the X axis of the screen, but also reading through the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/insets#ime-animations) as to make sure you're using the right kind of padding.  The `.imePadding()` may not be exactly what you want, but I think starting off the with the ime padding is a good start overall.

Comment: please see the [gist](https://gist.github.com/mcicishvilii/bbe9ae7f599d3b235a38eba147852c18)

Comment: for now its too hard for me but i found a solution to completely get rid of PupUp and just use lazycolumn and style it. so its fine now. but still very confusing